# How to debug cron jobs in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cron

I have read some posts regarding this topic. But not so clear. Thats why i am asking again.

I am trying to debug a cron job in the plugin disqus-comment-system.

```
$ts = time() + 300;
wp_schedule_single_event($ts, 'dsq_sync_forum');

add_action('dsq_sync_forum', 'dsq_sync_forum');

function dsq_sync_forum($last_comment_id=false, $force=false) {

.........some code

}
```

I am using vim and vdebug. I tried many times but its doesnot debug the function dsq_sync_forum.

I googled regarding this, but not understood the solutions.

Comment: Those particular debugging methods aside, first thing I'd try is removing the parameters from your function, because your event declaration does not have any arguments to send.

Comment: Are the hook and the function allowed to have the same name? I'm not sure about that, you might try changing that though.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot debug your cron tasks when browsing your website because they are triggered with the `wp_remote_post()` function.
The function will send a `http` request to the `wp-cron.php` file that will execute your cron jobs.

If you want to debug it easily (xdebug or var_dump / die), you can set the `disable_wp_cron` constant to true (1). This will prevent WordPress to call the `wp-cron.php` file when you browse the website.

Then you can manually browse the URL `mywebsite.com/wp-cron.php` to debug and display whatever variable you need.

When you call the `wp-cron.php` URL it will trigger the process. It will look in the `wp_options` table for an option named `cron` which contains all the registered jobs and their next schedules.
If a schedule is met, the task is run, else the process ends silently.

Comment: Hey @tim, can you please explain a little more about browsing `wp-cron.php`? 
I got many methods inside my `functions.php`, which I am running using customized cron tasks. Are they accessible as well from `wp-cron?
I have opened the page and saw nothing. How can you see the tasks in this page?

Comment: See my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with WP Cron itself. Actions from WP Cron doesn't fire exactly when defined, but only when someone will trigger them (with a page view).

You can use my [Advanced Cron Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-cron-manager/) plugin to see what's going on.